# Using lambdas as callback functions

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, esp32, lambda

Using the [Ticker](https://github.com/bertmelis/Ticker-esp32/blob/master/src/ESP32Ticker.h) library for the ESP32, how can I use a lambda as an argument to the *attach* method?

```
tickerSystemManager.attach(1000, [&](){
  systemManager->sync();
});
```

Attempting to use the above, I get the following error:

```
Matrx.cpp:11:4: error: no matching function for call to 'Ticker::attach(int, Matrx::setup()::<lambda()>)'
...
Ticker.h:40:8: note: candidate: void Ticker::attach(float, Ticker::callback_t)
```

How can I capp a lambda into this method?

Comment: Lambda expressions that take have no captures generate some implementation type that is implicitly convertible to a basic pointer to function type.  Lambda expressions that have a capture group don't qualify for that and are generally speaking not going to be compatible, because in practice what the compiler generates is a class whose members represent the captures, which makes the pointer into a pointer to class member function and therefore incompatible with regular pointer to function.

Comment: So what can I do to call the _sync_ method of my object? It seems as if every attempt to do so give me some error or another.

Comment: If systemManager is a global, just remove the `&` from the capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @timemage explains in a comment, you cannot pass a capturing lambda
to a function that expects a plain pointer to function. There is,
however, a way out of this: the `Ticker` class provides an overload of
the `attach()` method that allows you to provide a parameter of any type
to tour callback:

```cpp
template<typename TArg>
void attach(float seconds, void (*callback)(TArg), TArg arg)
```

You can use this version of `attach()` and provide it both

- a non-capturing lambda that gets a pointer to `systemManager`
- that pointer as a third argument.

**Edit**: I did a few tests, and it seems my compiler cannot properly
perform template argument deduction in this case, but the approach works
if you explicitly specialize the template. Namely:

```cpp
tickerSystemManager.attach<typeof systemManager>(
    1000,
    [](typeof systemManager p){ p->sync(); },
    systemManager);
```

Comment: You've managed to make this on topic.  Might as well go a step further and show the user-data-capable overload in the context of a lambda expression.

Comment: @timemage: Good  suggestion. I updated the answer.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, this compiled and seems to run as expected! I am still trying to learn Cpp while setting up an ESP project and you are definitely giving me more to look into!